# howto set a category for a webform/entityform question ...?

Tags: 7, views, webforms, entities

I need to have students fill out ~50 questions on their studies abroad -- and show their answers on pages in drupal (form submissions are drupal content). questions can belong to 10 different categories. I'm trying to use either [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) or [entityform](http://drupal.org/project/entityform) ... but coming up blank here on how to give each question an associated category Views can use.

I can use [field_group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) to group questions under a specific category, but the `field_group` setting is not useable in Views. I'm aiming for a view of something like this photoshop mockup:
[image]

Any ideas are appreciated :)

I have looked into making a Views Filter for the field_group field. But field_group stores the data for a group in a serialized `$data` field per Group ... I dont think views as an sql-query-builder can do anything meaningful with data in that format (or am I wrong) ... ?

Comment: You might also want to take into account that you cannot access webform submissions data from Views.

Comment: ya i kinda know that. there are ways of getting submission data in Views with webform in D6 ... i'm just looking at all possible modules that _might_ offer a solution.

Comment: is there any reason you wouldn't use webform entity as suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [Webform Entity](http://drupal.org/project/webform_entity) module. It uses Webform to create the forms but the content that is created is a full-fledged entity instead of just a serialized array in the database. That means full Views support etc.

For a category you can use a field list in the webform which can become a taxonomy field or field list in the entity that can be used as an exposed filter in Views.

To set this up just go to "admin/config/content/webform/entities/webform/" and click "Create" to create an entity webform

[image]

Then add fields to the entity:
[image]

Now, when you create a webform, the fields from the webform entity will appear on your node:

[image]

Finally, in Views, create a new view with the webform subsmissions as a base table:

[image]

and the fields attached to webforms can be used as exposed filters, fields and all other things views:

[image]

Comment: This appears to work for most cases. But i'm having trouble getting this work to show ~5-10 question associated with a given category. I have attempted to make N entity webforms, 1 for each category .... but am having trouble with the Views filter across all these views ...

Comment: I think that to limit each grouped category to a certain number (in your question it looks like 2) I think you might need to create your own style plugin in views. You might try using Views Accordion to limit the size of the page and let users click expand the answers.